# Java XML Web Service

Tags: java, xml, soap

for a school project I'm trying to create my own SOAP web service.
While doing some work an error occur.

public class ServerMain {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8976/s19103/people",
                new PersonServiceImpl());

        LOGGER.info("Service started");
        System.out.println("START");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:803)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:180)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:140)
at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:255)
at example.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:461)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:455)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1174)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:262)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:249)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:442)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:652)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:599)
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl$2.run(ProviderImpl.java:274)
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl$2.run(ProviderImpl.java:271)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.getEPRJaxbContext(ProviderImpl.java:271)
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.<clinit>(ProviderImpl.java:96)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 36 more
```

What does it mean and what do I have to do to run my program?
Even when I try to run the automaticaly generated example HelloWorld I get the same error.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource. Have you imported the classes you use?

Comment: I import javax.xml.ws.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

Comment: so not javax.activation.*?

Comment: Nope, I have just tried and got that it does not exist